# Articles about Django project structure

Tags: django, model-view-controller

Who could recommend any articles about apps and model structure in Django that covers information on how I should allocate my code into several apps or packages. What questions should I ask myself to add ForeignKeys to the right place and when should I do the reverse - use backward relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer might be useful or utterly worthless, depending on where you're coming from and what experience you have with Django, but Django is probably the most well documented framework I've seen so far.

The Django website provides ALOT of information, and the tutorials cover the basics in most of the areas you'll need to touch when developing your application.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/

Of course, if you've already seen all this and are experienced with Django, just looking for some deeper insight, then disregard my advice.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at large open source django projects on github. django-sentry, askbot, django-piston, and most importantaly django iteself!!! https://github.com/django/django,

Good database design is independent of it's implementation in django.  Learning something about basic relationships will help you.  As always wikipedia is a great place to start.
http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx